# Как оформить активити программы?

Tags: activity, android, android-sdk

Как сделать оформление программы не с помощью стандартного андроидовского GUI, а например как это сделано в приложении Вконтакте или в Play Market?

Comment: Вы не поверите, но почти все программы используют именно стандартные элементы GUI Android.    Нужно всего лишь правильно их настроить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы был шустрый интерфейс юзайте [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), боковое меню делается с помощью [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), также рекомендую ознакомиться с [Design patterns](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html) 
если же хочется именно как в вк то он сделан с использованием [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) ─ тогда еще выше описанных аналогов от гугла не было, хотя я все же рекомендую использовать библиотеки от гугла, будет ли поддерживаться в дальнейшем actionbarsherlock  неизвестно, хотя довольно таки качественная библиотека

Comment: что касается  ABS, то ее хватит на жизнь старого андроида. т.к. версия, где нет поддержки ActionBar, проживет совсем не долго

Comment: так уже в сапорте же есть

Comment: да, я знаю, это так, к слову просто :)